# Manual for Bitcoin-Qt on Mac OS X

Tags: bitcoin-core, mac

Is there a manual for [Bitcoin-Qt](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin-Qt) on the Mac OS X?

Specifically, I'd like to move my `wallet.dat` to a different folder (a [TrueCrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueCrypt) volume) and if/how I may configure `bitcoin.conf` so that the software autopoints to that folder upon launch. Is it possible to have `wallet.dat` in one directory and the blockchain files in a separate directory?

Secondarily, I'd like to learn about all possible configuration settings - both from the shell prompt as well as from `bitcoin.conf`. Can `bitcoin.conf` contain just one or two lines for desired configuration settings?

Answer (score 1):

Start Bitcoin-qt, 
click help, 
click debug window,
click show below command-line options,
click show details

Comment: Thanks! That helped. I also found this wiki page https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Bitcoin.conf_Configuration_File